# How to reset Delphi Tadocommand parameters

Tags: delphi, parameters, ado

I have a Tadocommand on my datamodule which is connected to a MSSQL storedproc. The storedproc is used to update a table.
In my code I call the the tadocommand in the beforeupdaterecord method of one of my Tclientdatasets.

first I supply values to the tadocommand parameters using the deltads.fieldbyname().newvalue of the Tclientdataset then I call the execute procedure. It works ok for the first update but if i try to do a next update it generates "error changing varchar to datetime".

if i dynamically create the tadocommand in the beforeupdaterecord method i.e

```
sp1_editcontract:=Tadocommand.Create(nil);
sp1_editcontract.CommandType:=cmdStoredProc;
sp1_editcontract.Connection:=DMDBconn.DBConn;
sp1_editcontract.CommandText:='EditContract';
sp1_editcontract.Parameters.Refresh; 
//assign parameter values
sp1_editcontract.execute;
sp1_editcontract.free;
```

it works without any errors. I think there is some problem with the parameters values when using the static Tadocommand on the datamodule.

why does multiple update generate an error when using a static created tadocommand and not for the dynamically created tadocommand?

Comment: any idea why it works for the dynamically created tadocommand and not the one on the datamodule

Comment: are you changing the command (procedure name to be called) between calls?

Comment: the connection, commandtype  properties of both adocommand's are exactly the same and are not changed between calls. The only difference is with the commandtext property.. in the object inspector the static adocommand commandtext is "Editcontract;1" but the dynamic adocommand it's just "EditContract"

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are referring to `TDatasetProvider.BeforeUpdateRecord` and not `TClientDataSet.BeforeUpdateRecord`.

Its kinda hard to say from the information you've provided (you don't indicate the data types or order of the arguments for the stored procedure). The error message is coming from the SQL Server engine. I would make sure the values being assigned to the parameters are always being set in the correct order. Also try to identify which parameter is causing the error. If you can reliably reproduce it in your client code you may try calling the stored procedure in SSMS passing the same values that are causing the error in the client application.

Once you identify the parameter you can check that its datatype is consistent between the ADOCommand, DatasetProvider and ClientDataset. If it changes type along the way that may be the cause of the error.

One last suggestion, make sure you set `TDatasetProvider.Applied := True` before exiting the `BeforeUpdateRecord` handler. This prevents the dataset provider from trying to apply the update using dynamic sql after you've already applied the updates. If the data in the client dataset was populated by a TADOQuery it may be attempting to update the tables directly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In order to clear all the existing parameters of the ADOCommand before adding new ones a used the following code:

```
while Command.Parameters.Count>0 do
  Command.Parameters.Delete(0);
```

`Parameters.Clear` should had worked, but it didn´t, so I decided to remove the parameters one by one. That fixed to me.